# Woocommerce Subscriptions - Remove the Tax from signup fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-subscriptions

I need to remove the **tax** from the **signup fee**, I can't see a way of having a tax on the subscription and not the signup fee.

I've tried using the filter: `woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string`. I can only manage to turn on or off the signup fee.

How can I remove tax from the **signup fee**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right hook to use, but it's not easy to get it working for that. So Here it's a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string`** that will replace the displayed signup fee price **"including taxes"** by the signup fee price **"excluding taxes"**.

I have separated in a function that you can reuse, the prices signup fee. It will return an array of prices (the price with / without taxes and the tax ).

Here is that code:

```
function get_price_sign_up_fee( $product ){
    $price_incl_tax = wcs_get_price_including_tax( $product, array( 'price' => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_sign_up_fee( $product ) ) );
    $price_excl_tax = wcs_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, array( 'price' => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_sign_up_fee( $product ) ) );
    $price_tax = $price_incl_tax - $price_excl_tax;

    return array( 'incl_tax' => $price_incl_tax, 'excl_tax' => $price_excl_tax, 'tax' => $price_tax );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'subscr_product_price_string', 10, 3 );
function subscr_product_price_string( $subscription_string, $product, $include ){
        //print_pr($subscription_string);

    if ( $include['sign_up_fee'] && WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_sign_up_fee( $product ) > 0 ) {
        $sign_up_fee = get_price_sign_up_fee( $product );
        // Replacing price to excluding taxes one
        $subscription_string = str_replace( wc_price($sign_up_fee['incl_tax']), wc_price($sign_up_fee['excl_tax']), $subscription_string );
    }
    return $subscription_string;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works.

> But in cart items the signup fee remain with taxes… but this is another thing (or another question)… So you will need to find the way to make changes on it too…

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec, that's brilliant. I'll take a look at the cart and how I can get it to show the fee without tax. Many thanks for your time and help.